# In LTspice, why does having these two transformer models create an error?

Tags: ltspice, error

I've run this circuit with all the inductors placed in the circuit with the appropriate 'K' commands and, although deeply slow in the simulation, it works just fine.

When I've placed them into models as shown:
[image: LTSpice Screenshot showing two large toroid transformers in Circuit]

One or the other toroid will cause an error. What I mean by 'one or the other' is that if I delete one and place it back in the circuit, then the other will cause the error, and vice-versa.

I think that means neither is at fault, per se, but having both at the same time cause conflict. The error is simple, "Unknown subcircuit called in: xx8 n014 p-1 np1 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 n042 85x55x20-multwind-8,7u"

That .asc (netlist) file is below as is the netlist (.asc) file for the the other toroid.

How do I overcome this issue now and in the future. For those who are asking 'Why do I want to do this, anyhow?' Because I want to see exactly HOW I wound this transformer for this circuit without going back and recalculating a. the toroid, b. each winding set as there are many, as you can plainly see.

And, maybe I'm fooling myself, there might be a small performance improvement in simulation, because I sure would like to see what this does at 1 second in less than three days.

Anyways, here are the three netlists (including the main circuit)

Thanks for any help!

```
* \documents\ltspicexvii\lib\sym\robspersonalsym\toroids\85x55x20-multwind-8,7u.asc
.subckt 85x55x20-multwind-8,7u Grnd PriIn sec1 sec1b sec2 sec3 sec4 sec5 sec6 sec7
PriOut
L1 PriOut PriIn 39.412m Ipk=380.599 Rser=606.94m
L2 sec2 Grnd 35.47µ Ipk=12686.64 Rser=18.21m
L3 sec3 Grnd 35.47µ Ipk=12686.64 Rser=18.21m
L4 sec4 Grnd 35.47µ Ipk=12686.64 Rser=18.21m
L5 sec5 Grnd 35.47µ Ipk=12686.64 Rser=18.21m
L6 sec6 Grnd 35.47µ Ipk=12686.64 Rser=18.21m
L7 sec7 Grnd 35.47µ Ipk=12686.64 Rser=18.21m
L8 sec1 sec1b 140.524µ Ipk=1.337 Rser=11.884m
K1 L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 L6 L7 L8 .99
.ends 85x55x20-multwind-8,7u

* \documents\ltspicexvii\lib\sym\robspersonalsym\toroids\85x55x20-multwind-3,9u.asc

.subckt 85x55x20-multwind-3,9u b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 TLnp2 TLnp3 
TLnp4 TLnp5 TLnp6 TLp1 TLp2 TLp3 TLp4 TLp5 TLp6 TLnp1 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7
L1 c1 N001 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L2 v1 N001 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L3 c2 N002 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L4 c3 N003 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L5 c4 N004 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L6 c5 N005 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L7 c6 N006 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L8 c7 N007 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L9 N007 b7 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L10 N006 b6 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L11 N005 b5 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L12 N004 b4 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L13 N003 b3 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L14 N002 b2 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L15 N001 b1 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L16 v2 N002 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L17 v3 N003 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L18 v4 N004 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L19 v6 N006 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L20 v5 N005 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L21 v7 N007 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L22 TLnp1 TLp1 141.88µ Ipk=6343.32 Rser=36.42m
L23 NC_01 NC_02 141.88µ Ipk=6343.32 Rser=36.42m
L26 TLnp5 TLp5 141.88µ Ipk=6343.32 Rser=36.42m
L27 TLnp6 TLp6 141.88µ Ipk=6343.32 Rser=36.42m
L24 TLnp3 TLp3 141.88µ Ipk=6343.32 Rser=36.42m
L25 NC_03 NC_04 141.88µ Ipk=6343.32 Rser=36.42m
K2 L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 L6 L7 L8 L9 L10 L11 L12 L13 L14 L15 L16 L17 L18 L19 L20 L21 L22 L23 L24 L25 L26 L27 .99
.ends 85x55x20-multwind-3,9u
```

```
* \Documents\LTspiceXVII\Schematics\Low Current Boost Converter IV.asc
Q1 0 N047 gate 0 2N3906
D9 N047 gate 1N4148
R4 N016 N015 1,454.54 tol=.001 pwr=5
V1 N015 0 1.6
R5 N021 N020 1,454.54 tol=.001 pwr=5
V2 N020 0 1.6
R7 N044 N043 1,454.54 tol=.001 pwr=5
V4 N043 0 1.6
R8 N034 N033 1,454.54 tol=.001 pwr=5
V5 N033 0 1.6
R9 N031 N030 1,454.54 tol=.001 pwr=5
V6 N030 0 1.6
R10 N025 N024 1,454.54 tol=.001 pwr=5
V7 N024 0 1.6
R6 N005 N004 2k tol=1 pwr=.25
C1 N005 N004 2n V=2K Irms=0 Rser=0.0585952 Lser=385.402p
D3 N013 N014 1N5818
R2 N036 N035 2k tol=1 pwr=.25
C4 N036 N035 2n V=2K Irms=0 Rser=0.0585952 Lser=385.402p
L21 N046 N045 150µ Ipk=0.71 Rser=0.61 Rpar=106676 Cpar=10.254p mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="744787151 WE-PD2SR 7850"
Q3 N046 N036 0 0 BC337-40
D1 N046 N047 1N5818
XX1 N044 N035 N045 toroid-blockosc-25x14x10
XU1 N042 gate 0 NX3008NBK
XU2 N013 N005 N022 TIP120
R1 stage1 gate1 470k tol=2 pwr=.25
R3 N007 gate1 22 tol=2 pwr=.25
C3 gate1 0 0.001µ V=50 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0 mfg="Murata" pn="GCM155R71H102JA37" type="X7R"
R13 N011 0 1k tol=1 pwr=.25
R11 stage1 N011 1k tol=1 pwr=.25
Q2 N011 N017 0 0 2N3904_Cordell
Q4 N017 N011 N007 0 2N3906
XU5 N003 gate1 0 NX3008NBK
D7 0 N003 1N5818
L5 N003 N002 1.01m Ipk=2378.74 Rser=97.111m
R29 N001 MainB 2k tol=1 pwr=.25
C6 N001 MainB 2n V=2K Irms=0 Rser=0.0585952 Lser=385.402p
L2 N010 MainC 10µ Ipk=2.6 Rser=0.0365 Rpar=10358 Cpar=3.805p mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="744787100 WE-PD2SR 7850"
Q13 N010 N001 N018 0 BC337-40
D10 N010 stage1 1N5818
D22 N003 ST1-OUT 1N5818
C2 stage1 0 10µ V=50 Irms=33m Rser=1.69799 Lser=2.84001n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="865090643009 WCAP-ASLU 6,3x5,5" type="Al electrolytic"
D23 stage1 N002 1N5818
C31 ST1-OUT 0 100µ V=50 Irms=210m Rser=0.45 Lser=0 mfg="Nichicon" pn="UPR1H101MPH" type="Al electrolytic"
R76 N018 0 10 tol=1 pwr=1
XX2 N016 N004 N019 toroid-blockosc-25x14x10
XX3 N021 N004 N019 toroid-blockosc-25x14x10
XX4 N025 N004 N019 toroid-blockosc-25x14x10
XX5 N031 N004 N019 toroid-blockosc-25x14x10
XX6 N034 N004 N019 toroid-blockosc-25x14x10
L23 N013 N019 10µ Ipk=2.6 Rser=0.0365 Rpar=10358 Cpar=3.805p mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="744787100 WE-PD2SR 7850"
R12 N022 0 10 tol=1 pwr=1
C5 N014 N022 0.001µ V=50 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0 mfg="Murata" pn="GCM155R71H102JA37" type="X7R"
R14 N023 BB1 2k tol=1 pwr=.25
C56 N023 BB1 2n V=2K Irms=0 Rser=0.0585952 Lser=385.402p
Q5 np1 N023 N032 0 BC337-40
D62 np1 B1 1N5818
R15 N032 0 10 tol=1 pwr=1
R16 N037 BB2 2k tol=1 pwr=.25
C63 N037 BB2 2n V=2K Irms=0 Rser=0.0585952 Lser=385.402p
Q6 TLp1 N037 N048 0 BC337-40
D63 TLp1 B1 1N5818
R17 N048 0 10 tol=1 pwr=1
R18 N038 BB3 2k tol=1 pwr=.25
C65 N038 BB3 2n V=2K Irms=0 Rser=0.0585952 Lser=385.402p
Q7 TLp2 N038 N049 0 BC337-40
D64 TLp2 B1 1N5818
R19 N049 0 10 tol=1 pwr=1
R20 N039 BC4 2k tol=1 pwr=.25
C67 N039 BC4 2n V=2K Irms=0 Rser=0.0585952 Lser=385.402p
Q8 TLp3 N039 N050 0 BC337-40
D65 TLp3 B1 1N5818
R21 N050 0 10 tol=1 pwr=1
R22 N040 BB5 2k tol=1 pwr=.25
C72 N040 BB5 2n V=2K Irms=0 Rser=0.0585952 Lser=385.402p
Q9 TLp4 N040 N051 0 BC337-40
D66 TLp4 B1 1N5818
R23 N051 0 10 tol=1 pwr=1
R24 N041 BB6 2k tol=1 pwr=.25
C64 N041 BB6 2n V=2K Irms=0 Rser=0.0585952 Lser=385.402p
Q10 TLp5 N041 N052 0 BC337-40
D67 TLp5 B1 1N5818
R25 N052 0 10 tol=1 pwr=1
C57 B1 0 10µ V=50 Irms=120m Rser=1.604 Lser=3.33403n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="860160672009 WCAP-ATLL 5x11" type="Al electrolytic"
Q11 N008 N012 0 0 2N3904_Cordell
R31 Ch_Pump7 N008 1k tol=1 pwr=.25
R32 N012 Ch_Pump7 10k tol=1 pwr=.25
R33 N009 N008 1k tol=1 pwr=.25
Q15 N006 N009 Ch_Pump7 0 2N3906
R34 N006 N012 1k tol=1 pwr=.25
R26 N006 0 510 tol=2 pwr=.25
R27 Main_In N006 100 tol=2 pwr=1
Q12 N027 N029 0 0 2N3904_Cordell
R28 B1 N027 2.2k tol=1 pwr=.25
R30 N029 B1 22k tol=1 pwr=.25
R35 N028 N027 2.2k tol=1 pwr=.25
Q14 N026 N028 B1 0 2N3906
R36 N026 N029 10.350k tol=1 pwr=.25
R37 N026 0 330 tol=2 pwr=.25
R38 2-ch7 N026 200 tol=2 pwr=.25
C70 B1 0 0.1µ V=63 Irms=1.3m Rser=3.1361 Lser=3.8088n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="860020772001 WCAP-ATG5 5x11" type="Al electrolytic"
C71 B1 0 0.1µ V=63 Irms=1.3m Rser=3.1361 Lser=3.8088n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="860020772001 WCAP-ATG5 5x11" type="Al electrolytic"
C73 B1 0 0.1µ V=63 Irms=1.3m Rser=3.1361 Lser=3.8088n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="860020772001 WCAP-ATG5 5x11" type="Al electrolytic"
C74 B1 0 0.1µ V=63 Irms=1.3m Rser=3.1361 Lser=3.8088n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="860020772001 WCAP-ATG5 5x11" type="Al electrolytic"
C75 B1 0 0.1µ V=63 Irms=1.3m Rser=3.1361 Lser=3.8088n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="860020772001 WCAP-ATG5 5x11" type="Al electrolytic"
XX7 0 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 2-ch7 p1 Ch_Pump Ch_Pump2 Ch_Pump3 Ch_Pump4 Ch_Pump5 Ch_Pump6 Ch_Pump7 chargepump
XX9 BB1 BB2 BB3 TLnp3 BB5 BB6 MainB TLnp6 TLnp1 TLnp2 BC4 TLnp4 TLnp5 MainC TLnp2 TLnp3 TLnp4 TLnp5 TLnp6 TLp1 TLp2 TLp3 TLp4 TLp5 p-1 TLnp1 Ch_Pump Ch_Pump2 Ch_Pump3 Ch_Pump4 Ch_Pump5 Ch_Pump6 Main_In 85x55x20-multwind-3,9u

XX8 0 N014 p-1 np1 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 N042 85x55x20-multwind-8,7u

* block symbol definitions
.subckt toroid-blockosc-25x14x10 In OutA OutB
L1 N001 OutA 194.4µ Ipk=2.5 Rser=27.16m Rpar=11590 Cpar=6.62p
L2 OutB N001 194.4µ Ipk=2.5 Rser=27.16m Rpar=11590 Cpar=6.62p
L3 N001 In 21.6µ Ipk=7.5 Rser=9.05m Rpar=376.8 Cpar=0
K L1 L2 L3 1
.ends toroid-blockosc-25x14x10

.subckt chargepump Ground In1 In2 In3 In4 In5 In6 In7 Osc Out1 Out2 Out3 Out4 Out5 Out6 Out7
C1 N013 Osc 0.001µ V=50 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0 mfg="Murata" pn="GCM155R71H102JA37" type="X7R"
D1 In1 N001 1N5818
C2 N001 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
D2 N001 N002 1N5818
D3 N002 N003 1N5818
D4 N003 N004 1N5818
D5 N004 N005 1N5818
D6 N005 N006 1N5818
D7 N006 Out1 1N5818
D8 Ground Osc 1N4001
D9 Ground In1 1N4001
C3 Out1 Ground 0.1µ V=63 Irms=1.3m Rser=3.1361 Lser=3.8088n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="860020772001 WCAP-ATG5 5x11" type="Al electrolytic"
C4 N002 N013 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C5 N003 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C6 N004 N013 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C7 N005 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C8 N006 N013 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C9 N027 Osc 0.001µ V=50 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0 mfg="Murata" pn="GCM155R71H102JA37" type="X7R"
D10 In2 N015 1N5818
C10 N015 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
D11 N015 N016 1N5818
D12 N016 N017 1N5818
D13 N017 N018 1N5818
D14 N018 N019 1N5818
D15 N019 N020 1N5818
D16 N020 Out2 1N5818
D17 Ground Osc 1N4001
D18 Ground In2 1N4001
C11 Out2 Ground 0.1µ V=63 Irms=1.3m Rser=3.1361 Lser=3.8088n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="860020772001 WCAP-ATG5 5x11" type="Al electrolytic"
C12 N016 N027 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C13 N017 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C14 N018 N027 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C15 N019 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C16 N020 N027 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C17 N041 Osc 0.001µ V=50 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0 mfg="Murata" pn="GCM155R71H102JA37" type="X7R"
D19 In3 N029 1N5818
C18 N029 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
D20 N029 N030 1N5818
D21 N030 N031 1N5818
D22 N031 N032 1N5818
D23 N032 N033 1N5818
D24 N033 N034 1N5818
D25 N034 Out3 1N5818
D26 Ground Osc 1N4001
D27 Ground In3 1N4001
C19 Out3 Ground 0.1µ V=63 Irms=1.3m Rser=3.1361 Lser=3.8088n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="860020772001 WCAP-ATG5 5x11" type="Al electrolytic"
C20 N030 N041 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C21 N031 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C22 N032 N041 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C23 N033 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C24 N034 N041 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C25 N049 Osc 0.001µ V=50 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0 mfg="Murata" pn="GCM155R71H102JA37" type="X7R"
D28 In4 N043 1N5818
C26 N043 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
D29 N043 N044 1N5818
D30 N044 N045 1N5818
D31 N045 N046 1N5818
D32 N046 N047 1N5818
D33 N047 N048 1N5818
D34 N048 Out4 1N5818

D35 Ground Osc 1N4001
D36 Ground In4 1N4001
C27 Out4 Ground 0.1µ V=63 Irms=1.3m Rser=3.1361 Lser=3.8088n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="860020772001 WCAP-ATG5 5x11" type="Al electrolytic"
C28 N044 N049 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C29 N045 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C30 N046 N049 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C31 N047 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C32 N048 N049 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C33 N014 Osc 0.001µ V=50 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0 mfg="Murata" pn="GCM155R71H102JA37" type="X7R"
D37 In5 N007 1N5818
C34 N007 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
D38 N007 N008 1N5818
D39 N008 N009 1N5818
D40 N009 N010 1N5818
D41 N010 N011 1N5818
D42 N011 N012 1N5818
D43 N012 Out5 1N5818
D44 Ground Osc 1N4001
D45 Ground In5 1N4001
C35 Out5 Ground 0.1µ V=63 Irms=1.3m Rser=3.1361 Lser=3.8088n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="860020772001 WCAP-ATG5 5x11" type="Al electrolytic"
C36 N008 N014 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C37 N009 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C38 N010 N014 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C39 N011 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C40 N012 N014 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C41 N028 Osc 0.001µ V=50 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0 mfg="Murata" pn="GCM155R71H102JA37" type="X7R"
D46 In6 N021 1N5818
C42 N021 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
D47 N021 N022 1N5818
D48 N022 N023 1N5818
D49 N023 N024 1N5818
D50 N024 N025 1N5818
D51 N025 N026 1N5818
D52 N026 Out6 1N5818
D53 Ground Osc 1N4001
D54 Ground In6 1N4001
C43 Out6 Ground 0.1µ V=63 Irms=1.3m Rser=3.1361 Lser=3.8088n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="860020772001 WCAP-ATG5 5x11" type="Al electrolytic"
C44 N022 N028 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C45 N023 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C46 N024 N028 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C47 N025 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C48 N026 N028 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C49 N042 Osc 0.001µ V=50 Irms=0 Rser=0 Lser=0 mfg="Murata" pn="GCM155R71H102JA37" type="X7R"
D55 In7 N035 1N5818
C50 N035 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
D56 N035 N036 1N5818
D57 N036 N037 1N5818
D58 N037 N038 1N5818
D59 N038 N039 1N5818
D60 N039 N040 1N5818
D61 N040 Out7 1N5818
D62 Ground Osc 1N4001
D63 Ground In7 1N4001
C51 Out7 Ground 0.1µ V=63 Irms=1.3m Rser=3.1361 Lser=3.8088n mfg="Würth Elektronik" pn="860020772001 WCAP-ATG5 5x11" type="Al electrolytic"
C52 N036 N042 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C53 N037 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C54 N038 N042 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C55 N039 Ground 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
C56 N040 N042 0.01µ V=10 Irms=291m Rser=0.34258 Lser=0 mfg="KEMET" pn="C0805F103K8RAC" type="X7R"
.ends chargepump

.subckt 85x55x20-multwind-3,9u b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 TLnp2 TLnp3 TLnp4 TLnp5 TLnp6 TLp1 TLp2 TLp3 TLp4 TLp5 TLp6 TLnp1 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7
L1 c1 N001 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L2 v1 N001 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L3 c2 N002 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L4 c3 N003 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L5 c4 N004 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L6 c5 N005 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L7 c6 N006 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L8 c7 N007 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L9 N007 b7 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L10 N006 b6 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L11 N005 b5 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L12 N004 b4 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L13 N003 b3 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L14 N002 b2 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L15 N001 b1 98.53µ Ipk=7611.982 Rser=30.347m
L16 v2 N002 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L17 v3 N003 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L18 v4 N004 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L19 v6 N006 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L20 v5 N005 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L21 v7 N007 15.764µ Ipk=19029.95 Rser=12.139M
L22 TLnp1 TLp1 141.88µ Ipk=6343.32 Rser=36.42m
L23 NC_01 NC_02 141.88µ Ipk=6343.32 Rser=36.42m
L26 TLnp5 TLp5 141.88µ Ipk=6343.32 Rser=36.42m
L27 TLnp6 TLp6 141.88µ Ipk=6343.32 Rser=36.42m
L24 TLnp3 TLp3 141.88µ Ipk=6343.32 Rser=36.42m
L25 NC_03 NC_04 141.88µ Ipk=6343.32 Rser=36.42m
K2 L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 L6 L7 L8 L9 L10 L11 L12 L13 L14 L15 L16 L17 L18 L19 L20 L21 L22 L23 L24 L25 L26 L27 .99
.ends 85x55x20-multwind-3,9u

.subckt 85x55x20-multwind-8,7u Grnd PriIn sec1 sec1b sec2 sec3 sec4 sec5 sec6 sec7 PriOut
L1 PriOut PriIn 39.412m Ipk=380.599 Rser=606.94m
L2 sec2 Grnd 35.47µ Ipk=12686.64 Rser=18.21m
L3 sec3 Grnd 35.47µ Ipk=12686.64 Rser=18.21m
L4 sec4 Grnd 35.47µ Ipk=12686.64 Rser=18.21m
L5 sec5 Grnd 35.47µ Ipk=12686.64 Rser=18.21m
L6 sec6 Grnd 35.47µ Ipk=12686.64 Rser=18.21m
L7 sec7 Grnd 35.47µ Ipk=12686.64 Rser=18.21m
L8 sec1 sec1b 140.524µ Ipk=1.337 Rser=11.884m
K1 L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 L6 L7 L8 .99
.ends 85x55x20-multwind-8,7u

.model D D
.lib \Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.dio
.model NPN NPN
.model PNP PNP
.lib \Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\cmp\standard.bjt
.tran 0 .3 .295 .0000001
.lib \Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\sym\RobsPersonalSym\NX3008NBK.lib
.lib Sborka.lib
.backanno
.end
```

Comment: Any way to upload hi-res images of your schematic?  It's impossible to see anything with such a low-res image.  Can even split them up into several screenshots to make it even more clear.

Comment: @SteKulov I've added the netlist of the complete circuit which may be more helpful. Like I said, the circuit is working when the transformer's inductors and k .op statements are in the circuit rather than in separate subcircuits. So the answer should be in the netlist. The image is to give the overview. You can load the netlist into ltspice and create assemblies for the two transformers to simulate at home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put commas in your subcircuit names.  Commas are special characters and count the same as a blank space in SPICE syntax, i.e. they both are used to separate out data fields.  See Appendix 3 (paragraph 2) of [the original SPICE2 manual](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1975/9602.html) or Section 2.1 (paragraph 4) of [the SPICE3 manual](http://bear.ces.cwru.edu/eecs_cad/man_spice3_sec2.html).

Comment: Dots can be used, instead.

Comment: Lo and Behold! We have a winner! Thank you @SteKulov !! I used 3u9 and 8u7 in the names instead and it works great. Who knew. Wait, SteKulov did, that's who! And would you know, greater performance, it seems... about 20% maybe (5.4 us/s avg instead of 4.3 us/s ... still not awesome.. but better)